# parameterized test to check if constructor throws exception

Tags: java, junit4

I have a constructor that may throw an `IOException`:

```
public MyClass(string url) throws IOException { ... }
```

Now I want to test of the exception is thrown in certain scenarios using a parameterized test. Can I annotate my test-method with a value for `url` and the expected exception, something like this?

```
@Test("https://myHost/not.existsing", expected = IOException.class)
@Test("https://myHost/whrong.fileextension", expected = IOException.class)
public void MyTest(String url)
{
    Assert.Throws(expected);
}
```

Comment: @SDJ But I can´t see how I can provide the exception as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Junit 4 supports [Prameterized](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests). Try this:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Test {
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {     
                 { "https://myHost/whrong.fileextension" }, 
                 { "https://myHost/not.existsing"}  
           });
    }

    private String url;


    public Test(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Test(expected = IOException.class)
    public void test() throws IOException {
       MyClass myClass = new MyClass(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Woah, that´s really ugly. I suppose I´m going to Junit5. Thanks anyway.